# Android - Seekbar - Customize seekbar UI

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

Recently, I've been working with seekbar. I want to create seekbar have a small gap between thumb and progress bar like in the picture I attached. Can anyone help me or tell me how I can do. Thanks

[Seekbar sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6lWf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your thumb image have some spacing so this is happend.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by very simple, like  Brahgrav said, just redraw the thumb with spaced outside and set to android:thumb. I will attach a thumb image for you to see.

[Thumb image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QWv7.png)